# Help recreating algebraic reasoning on the Euclidean metric.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to recreate and formalize with Lean4 this hint from "Euclidean plane and its relatives" by Petrunin:

$$
\sqrt{(x_{1} + x_{2}) ^ {2} + (y_{1} + y_{2}) ^ {2}} \leq \sqrt{x_{1} ^ {2} + y_{1} ^ {2}} + \sqrt {x_{2} ^ {2} + y_{2} ^ {2}}
$$

Take the square of the left and the right-hand sides, simplify, take the square again and simplify again. You should get the following inequality:

$$
0 \leq (x_{1} \cdot y_{2} - x_{2} \cdot y_{1})^{2}
$$

Attempting this, all I can tell to do is to expand out all of the terms after squaring, and cancel out any like terms, which leads to a massive expression after the second time expanding out all of the terms which definitely does not easily cancel out to look like the second inequality. I am aware that there is more general ways to prove the inequality, but formalizing proofs of Cauchy's inequality and such has proven also to be a very difficult task. I would love some help to see the details in the algebra of how the first expression is supposed to simplify to the second. Thank you.

Also it would be helpful if it's possible to do backwards: starting with the second inequality and deriving the first. I didn't make much progress beyond expanding out the term, subtracting, and then applying square root to both sides, and was pretty uncertain how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use the triangle inequality to prove the second inequality. The first and **really important** point is that the second inequality is trivial! This is true because, in fact, the square of any real number is non-negative! This is why in general one  begins with one such inequality and derives the first one which is much less trivial. What you can actually do is begin with the first inequality, arrive on the second one and the "reverse engineer" your steps. This is **not** always feasible. In our case$^{[1]}$, this works. But it is **not** the general, optimal or recommended way to derive relevant inequalities! This is probably circular in most proofs of the triangle inequality!!

---

With that said, we can get from the first inequality to the second one using the method you described. Square both sides to get:

$$(x_1+x_2)^2 + (y_1+y_2)^2 \le x_1^2 + x_2^2 + y_1^2 + y_2^2+ 2\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}\sqrt{x_1^2 + y_2^2}$$ and note that $(x_1+x_2)^2 + (y_1+y_2)^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2 +  y_1^2 + y_2^2 + 2x_1x_2 + 2y_1y_2.$ Here I just left the "unmixed" parts in evidence. Cancelling out those terms, you get:

$$ 2x_1x_2 + 2y_1y_2 \le 2\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2} \sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2}$$

Dividing by $2$, you have  $x_1x_2 + y_1y_2 \le \sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2}$. Squaring again...

$$(x_1x_2)^2 + (y_1y_2)^2 + 2x_1x_2y_1y_2 \le (x_1^2+y_1^2)(x_2^2+y_2^2).$$

Expanding the RHS using the distributive law, you have $(x_1x_2)^2+(y_1y_2)^2 + (x_1y_2)^2 + (x_2y_1)^2$.

Cancelling out the first two terms, we have

$$2x_1x_2y_1y_2 \le (x_1y_2)^2+(x_2y_1)^2.$$

But subtracting the LHS from both sides, you get that $$(x_1y_2)^2 - 2x_1x_2y_1y_2+(x_2y_1)^2 = (x_1y_2)^2 - 2(x_1y_2)(x_2y_1) + (x_2y_1)^2 \ge 0.$$ But this expression is precisely $(x_1y_2 - x_2y_1)^2$ and you're done.

However, remind: the second inequality is trivial. It is, generally, exactly from this inequality that the first one is proved to be true. You start from this inequality and in every step you can:

[1]: revert subtraction into addition, revert division into multiplication, squaring into square-roots (careful! This is valid because $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is monotonic!).

---

Comment: When going from the 'reverse' direction, from the trivial inequality to the triangle, the first square rooting seems difficult. Doesn't concluding that $\sqrt{(x_{1}x_{2} + y_{1}y_{2}) ^ {2}} = x_{1}x_{2} + y_{1}y_{2}$ on the LHS depend on $x_{1}x_{2} + y_{1}y_{2}$ being positive? That's not necessarily the case, right?

Comment: $\sqrt{t^2} = |t| \ge t.$